# Why is the type function returning False for a dictionary?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, types

After creating a dictionary, I run print(type([name]) is dict) and it says False. It returns true for list.

I'm testing this in a simple file because I believe this is the source of error in a larger program. In that program when I try to return the value by calling the key, it says I cannot call a key from a tuple, but I'm calling the key from a dictionary, not a tuple. When I enter the type function like this it returns `True` for `list`, not tuple or dictionary.

```
dictionary = {'value1':(1,2,3), 'value2':(4,5,6)}

print(type([dictionary]) is dict)
print(type([dictionary]) is list)
```

I expect to see `True` for `dict` and `False` for `list`. In actuality, I'm seeing `False` for `dict` and `True` for `list`.

Comment: `[dictionary]` is a list. `dictionary` is a dict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `type([dictionary])` is a `list` - the double brackets form a `list` containing the `dict`.

try `type(dictionary)` instead, it will be a `dict`

Answer (score 0):

Because type([dictionary]) is a list.Try type(dictionary) instead.